# cycle URLs by appending URL parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to set up a static page for a display that rotates through 'URLs' but not traditionally. Right now, my URL when page loads are`localcms.com/showDisplay.php?display=3` because the link that loads the page passes the value of `display` as 3. What I want to do with my javascript is have the initial page load put the `pageID` of the first JSON element into the URL like `localcms.com/showDisplay.php?display=3&pageID=104` and then after the duration (also value from JSON) rotate to the next and put the pageID of the next JSON element in the URL `localcms.com/showDisplay.php?display=3&pageID=116`.

The problem is, my initial page load just has the passed link with `?display=3` and I can't get the javascript to access the JSON properly so that anytime I visit `localcms.com/showDisplay.php?display=3` it automatically appends the first pageID, stays on that page for the duration of that element, and goes to the next.

In the body of my page I have:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($showDisplayResult)){
echo json_encode($row, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}?>
```

WHich is pulling from my main query and it prints the 2 records I have from that query in JSON:

```
{ "pageID": "104", 
    "page_type_id": "1", 
    "display_id": "3", 
    "slide_order": null, 
    "duration": "56", 
    "active": "1", 
    "background_img": null, 
    "panel_id": "96", 
    "panel_type_id": "1", 
    "page_id": "104", 
    "cont_id": "148", 
    "contID": "148",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nThis is full content<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>" }
{ "pageID": "116", 
    "page_type_id": "1", 
    "display_id": "3", 
    "slide_order": null, 
    "duration": "54", 
    "active": "1", 
    "background_img": "images\/BG_spring.svg", 
    "panel_id": "113", 
    "panel_type_id": "1", 
    "page_id": "116", 
    "cont_id": "165", 
    "contID": "165", 
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nThis background should be green<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>" }
```

And here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // encode your php array to json
let obj = <?php echo json_encode($row); ?>;

let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
params.set("pageID", obj.pageID);
params.set("display", obj.display_id);

let url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
let nextURL = url + "?" + params.toString();
window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = nextURL;
}, obj.duration * 1000);

console.log(obj);
</script>
```

How can I properly access the JSON and use it correctly in my script?

UPDATE:

Using this

```
<?php
// $row = '{ "pageID": "104", 
//     "page_type_id": "1", 
//     "display_id": "3", 
//     "slide_order": null, 
//     "duration": "56", 
//     "active": "1", 
//     "background_img": null, 
//     "panel_id": "96", 
//     "panel_type_id": "1", 
//     "page_id": "104", 
//     "cont_id": "148", 
//     "contID": "148",
//     "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nThis is full content<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>" }
// ';

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($showDisplayResult);
?>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // encode your php array to json
    let obj = <?php echo json_encode($row); ?>;

    obj = JSON.parse(obj);

    let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
    params.set("pageID", obj.pageID);
    params.set("display", obj.display_id);
    let url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    let nextURL = url + "?" + params.toString();
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = nextURL;
    }, obj.duration * 1000);

    console.log(obj);
</script>
```

I get this in the console
[image]

If I comment out the current row and uncomment the hardcoded array, it loads the correct object in the console but does not initially append the pageID to the URL

Answer (score 0):

Modified Your code:

```
<?php
$row = '{ "pageID": "104", 
    "page_type_id": "1", 
    "display_id": "3", 
    "slide_order": null, 
    "duration": "56", 
    "active": "1", 
    "background_img": null, 
    "panel_id": "96", 
    "panel_type_id": "1", 
    "page_id": "104", 
    "cont_id": "148", 
    "contID": "148",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nThis is full content<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>" }
';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // encode your php array to json
    let obj = <?php echo json_encode($row); ?>;

    obj = JSON.parse(obj);

    let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
    params.set("pageID", obj.pageID);
    params.set("display", obj.display_id);
    let url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    let nextURL = url + "?" + params.toString();
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = nextURL;
    }, obj.duration * 1000);

    console.log(obj);
</script>
```

It is working fine.

[image]

Comment: That's still not working though. First of all, I just used $row to take in my mysql result so even using hard coding for testing, I'm trying to show what it's returning from the database. But this does not append the pageID to the url nor does it refresh with the new one. Console.log says cannot read property 'pageID' of null

Comment: Use this:     obj = JSON.parse(obj);

Comment: I saw where you had that in your answer so I've used that to test. The issues are happening with that in place

Comment: I  attached Image in answer.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: I am seeing the object in the console but it doesn't append pageID=104 to the URL until after the first refresh. My goal is to have that happen on page load and then go on to the next pageID at refresh, does that make sense? I can try to clarify more maybe

Comment: Also when I go back to using ```$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($showDisplayResult)``` it won't even dump in the console and goest back to cannot read property

Comment: I've updated with current code and console screenshot, let me know if that will work

Comment: @kiran_malvi it's not working if I hard code multiple json elements in that way either, does it need to encode my JSON differently? I really appreaciate your help here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177312/discussion-between-kiran-malvi-and-tom-n).

Answer (score -4):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    // encode your php array to json taking php to a json file
    let obj = <?php echo json_encode($row); ?>;
    enter code here
    obj = JSON.parse(obj);

    let parameter = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
    paramameter.set("pageID", obj.pageID);
    parameter.set("display", obj.display_id);
    let url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    let nextURL = url + "?" + params.toString();
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = nextURL;
    }, obj.duration * 1000);

    console.log(obj);
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: its actually clear the $pageID and code is clear for someone to understand